# Validating user input as coordinates (A1...)

Tags: c++

I am struggling to find a way to break down an input from the user to a location on a chess board. For example (A1). I want to make sure that they have entered a Letter between A and H and a number between 1 and 8. Not sure if comparing ASCII is the best approach?

Using C++ this is a snippet of what I have attempted. startingp is the input from the user

```
char startChar = startingp[0];
int SCascii = startChar;
int startInt = startingp[1];

if (!(ascii_A <= SCascii >= ascii_H) || !(1 <= startInt >= 8))
{
    cout << "Your inputted move, " << startPos << ", is invalid." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the coordinates of the piece you want to move. (eg A1) : ";
    cin >> startingp;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
(ascii_A <= SCascii >= ascii_H)
```

is not correct. Or at least, I don't think it's what you mean. Instead, do:

```
((ascii_A <= SCascii) && (SCascii >= ascii_H))
```

Other than that, your logic seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I made a Chess game as well, and this is what I used to get the coordinates:

```
Position* Interface::askPosition()
{
    cout << "position: ";
    string inp;
    cin >> inp;
    while (!(isalpha(inp[0]) && isdigit(inp[1]))) {
        cout << "Please press CHAR + DIGIT\n";
        cin >> inp;
    }
    return new Position(inp[0] - 'A', inp[1] - '1');
}
```

It's a static method of a class called `Interface` and returned a pointer to a `Position` object. However, this might be not a `C++`-clean way

Comment: Note that you shall still have to check whether someone didn't press `Z1` or `A0` by asking the coordinates of the `Position` object and comparing it to `Board::size`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare it with characters, no need to convert it into an int (ASCII).

```
char startChar = startingp[0];
int SCascii = startChar;
int startInt = startingp[1];

if  (!(startChar>='A' && startChar<='H') || !(startInt>=1 && startInt<=8))
{
    cout << "Your inputted move, " << startPos << ", is invalid." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the coordinates of the piece you want to move. (eg A1) : ";
    cin >> startingp;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I would have thought this worked also but instead it is running the invalid input comment

Comment: Can you specify where you are getting invalid input comment?